# C++ Windows forms does not keep menu customizations

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, windows

I'm making a windows application in C++/CLI. There is an error while customizing the application menu. I have a class called `CustomMenuColorTable` as bellow:

```
namespace SassEngine {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class CustomMenuColorTable : public System::Windows::Forms::ProfessionalColorTable {
        public:
            CustomMenuColorTable();

            Color text_color = Color::FromArgb(241, 241, 241);
            Color main_window_bg_color = Color::FromArgb(45, 45, 48);
            Color button_hover_bg_color = Color::FromArgb(63, 63, 70);
            Color button_active_bg_color = Color::FromArgb(0, 122, 204);
            Color border_color = Color::FromArgb(78, 78, 80);

        public:

            property Color MenuBorder {
                public: virtual Color get() override {
                    return border_color;
                };
            };
    };
}
```

I have used it in my form class as below:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  ApplicationMenu;

void InitializeComponent(void) {
  this->ApplicationMenu = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
  // #begin
  this->ApplicationMenu->Renderer = (gcnew 
  System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(gcnew CustomMenuColorTable()));
  this->ApplicationMenu->ForeColor = 
  System::Drawing::Color::FromArgb(static_cast<System::Int32>(
                static_cast<System::Byte>(241)),
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(241)),
                static_cast<System::Int32>(static_cast<System::Byte>(241))
            );
 // #end
}
```

After doing this and I opening the form designer I keep getting this error,

> Could not find type 'CustomMenuColorTable'.  Please make sure
>   that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type
>   is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has
>   been successfully built using settings for your current platform or
>   Any CPU.0

But when I run the application it's working fine. But when i just something in form designer `// #begin` to `// #end` (commented in form class) is deleting.

Please help me to solve this I'm not much familiar with Windows API.

Comment: You must not edit InitializeComponent(), it is reserved for the designer.  Put your own code in the form's constructor, after the InitializeComponent call.  Do note `#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code`, visible in code from the project item template.  Generated code can and will be re-generated.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, it worked. If you can post this as an answer I would like to accept that. :)